WSL2 Windows, Zathura pdf viewer stops responding after letting pc sleep
The issue I am having is that after letting my pc go into sleep mode, zathura stops responding to any commands. I am using WSL2 with WSL version 2.2.4.0, zathura 0.4.9 pdf-poppler. I can add more details if needed.
To recreate, I can open a pdf with zathura and then put my pc to sleep. After I turn it on again, zathura (of course) is still open, but won't respond, even the close window cross doesn't do anything. To be clear I can still view the page, but cannot move the screen or anything else. If I manually close (task manager, hotbar or via command) and open zathura again everything seems to work fine again.
I wasn't able to find anybody else with this problem, or anything related, which is why I am asking here. Any help is appreciated.

What is the version of Ubuntu?

@David 22.04, to be more exact it says Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS and codename jammy.
